# How to get all tabs and execute javascript on certain tab id in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to build firefox extension which executes script in the tab. It can be easily done in chrome but I didn't find any api to do that in firefox.

Can you guys show me the way ?

My chrome extension code [is here on github](https://github.com/sbspk/Prepros/blob/master/chrome-extension/scripts/background.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight off the SDK home page is a link for "listing open pages."

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/list-open-tabs.html

Using the SDK is seriously much easier than trying to learn the ins and outs of the old API.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code for add-ons created from scratch:

```
var numTabs = gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes.length;
for (var i = 0; i < numTabs; i++) {
    var currentTab = gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[i];
    var currentBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(currentTab);
    var doc=currentBrowser.contentDocument;
    // Use gBrowser.selectedTab or doc.defaultView.location to filter
    // doc refers DOM for tab
}
```

Refer following url for more details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser